# Limit rows but increase if the result have values equals

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit

I have two tables: hospede and hospedagem.
I'm trying to limit the result to **3 rows with the highest values**, not just "**limit 3"**. So if some result of the "**sum**" have the same value should be increase the maximum result rows.

Current result:

```
"Sao Paulo";810.40
"Porto Alegre";810.40
"Cascavel";740.40
"Ijui";680.40
"Itapema";540.00
```

The expected result:

```
"Sao Paulo";810.40
"Porto Alegre";810.40
"Cascavel";740.40
"Ijui";680.40
```

My humble query:

```
select      cidade "Cidade", 
            sum(valorDiaria * (dataSaida - dataEntrada)) "Valor Total"
from        hospedagem h1, hospede h2
where       h1.codHospede = h2.codHospede
and         CURRENT_DATE - interval '3 months' < dataEntrada
group by    "Cidade"
order by    "Valor Total" desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()` or `rank()` depending on how you want to handle ties:

```
select "Cidade", "Valor Total"
from (select cidade as "Cidade", 
             sum(valorDiaria * (dataSaida - dataEntrada)) as  "Valor Total",
             dense_rank() over (order by sum(valorDiaria * (dataSaida - dataEntrada)) desc) as seqnum
      from hospedagem h1 join hospede h2
           on h1.codHospede = h2.codHospede
      where CURRENT_DATE - interval '3 months' < dataEntrada
      group by "Cidade"
     ) hh
where seqnum <= 3;
```

If your data is:

```
100
100
100
100
 90
 90
 80
 79
```

Then `dense_rank()` will return the first seven rows.  `rank()` will only return the first four.  `row_number()` would return the first 3.